# Why can't I delete directions by calling setMap(null)?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have to draw multiple direction like this :

A->B B->C C->D

on the same map.

This is working fine, but when I try to delete B->C, the direction is still on the map.

To draw a direction I do this :

```
      directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
        suppressMarkers: true,
        polylineOptions: polylineOptionsActual,
        preserveViewport: true
      });
      createItinerary : function(eventA, eventB, transportationMode, counter)
      {
            if (eventDate.getDate() == currentDay.getDate())
              directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
      }
```

Then, every time I delete a road, I call

```
if (directionsDisplay != null)
{
  directionsDisplay.setMap(null);
  directionsDisplay = null;
}
```

I can call it every time I want, the direction won't be removed even if directionDisplay is null.

I only have this bug when I have more than one direction.

Any idea of what could be wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer ... in a loop.  What you must do, is store that variable, in an array.

example (I assume some for-loop):

```
var directionsDisplayArray = [];
for(var i in data) {
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    suppressMarkers: true,
    polylineOptions: polylineOptionsActual,
    preserveViewport: true
  });
  directionsDisplayArray.push(directionsDisplay);
}
```

Then you can delete these displays in a loop

```
for(var i in directionsDisplayArray) {
  directionsDisplayArray[i].setMap(null);
}
```